# Change div id on button click function, to create a darkmode

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, darkmode

I'm trying to write a JavaScript that makes an id change its id on click. Basically, I would like to create a dark mode toggle button. Not sure what I'm doing wrong though.

HTML

```
<button id="nottebottone" class="notte">Attiva modalità notturna</button>
```

CSS

```
#Sito {
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(221, 241, 235);
    border: black ridge;
    border-width: 0.03cm;
}
```

Which I'm trying to change to:

```
#Nightmode {
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: rgb(255, 255, 255) ridge;
    border-width: 0.03cm;
    color: white;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
let bottonedarkmode = document.getElementById("nottebottone");

function attivadarkmode() {
   if (document.div.id == "Sito") {
       document.div.id = "Nightmode";
   }
   else {
       documento.div.id = "Sito";
   }
}

bottonedarkmode.addEventListener('click', attivadarkmode);
```

Click the button nottebottone to enable the id switch, but nothing happens.

Comment: If you are running that code you have an error that guides you to the root cause of your problem

Comment: it's best practice to style your elements with class and not with id, you can add and remove classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```js
let darkModeBtn = document.querySelector(".notte");

function attivadarkmode() {
  darkModeBtn.classList.toggle('light');
  darkModeBtn.classList.toggle('dark');
}

darkModeBtn.addEventListener('click', attivadarkmode);
```

```css
.notte {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.light {
  background-color: rgb(221, 241, 235);
  border: black ridge;
  border-width: 0.03cm;
}

.dark {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border: rgb(255, 255, 255) ridge;
  border-width: 0.03cm;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="nottebottone" class="notte light">Attiva modalità notturna</button>
```

At a first glance, I'm assuming the issue is that you typed `documento` instead of `document` in the `else` portion of your function, though I didn't check thouroughly.

Comment: Not working unfortunately :(

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about - when I try it, the code works fine. Did you run the snippet?

Comment: If you mean that the bug fix which I posted alongside the snippet is wrong, then that should be expected - I only said that I glanced. However, the snippet is perfectly correct.

Comment: The snippet is working, but not on the HTML page. Clicking on the button still does nothing.

Comment: Ohh - that's because this code's HTML is specially made for this environment - you need to add the basic skeleton of a HTML page, as well as the css and javascript links.

Comment: I did it!!! I modified a bit the code here and there and it finally worked. Thank you so so much!!!

Comment: If it works for you, then accept the answer so that people can see the solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you for changing ID:

```
document.getElementById('nottebottone').id = 'Nightmode';
```

Comment: This is inefficient as OP has already created a variable to substitute for the ```document.getElementById('nottebottone')``` portion of your solution.